# How to open a link in new tab using <a> tag in javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to open a link in new tab using a tag, the html for this looks like :

```
<a href=""
    onclick="window.open( urlvalue, '_blank' );">MyLink
</a>
```

How could i implement it using Jquery and Javascript.

Note: This  tag is inside a div, so I want to append the a tag inside that div as well.

Comment: Just use `$('a').trigger('click')`?

Comment: What's wrong with `<a href="[urlvalue]" target="_blank">MyLink</a>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery: (Given that there is an `<a>` element present)

```
$(function(){
   $('a').attr('target', '_blank').attr('href', 'YOUR_LINK').trigger('click')
});
```

**EDIT**

Another case (You have `<div>` element and you want to append a link inside it);

```
$(function(){
   $('div').append('<a href = "YOUR_LINK" target = "_blank">LINK</a>');
});
```

Comment: Under this code where should i specify the url that i want to go ?

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but i am new to web programming can you tell me where do we specify the text, clicking on which i will be redirected to my link in new tab ? Thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, do you want to create an `<a>` element using Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: I want to know both the approach using javascript as well as jquery.

Answer (score 7):

You just need to add like below, and it will work

```
<a href="URLValue" target="_blank" >My link</a>
```

Jquery code:-

```
$(this).find("a").attr("target", "_blank");
```

Comment: I want to know how to write the javascript code for the following html ?

Answer (score 0):

If it's Javascript you need... From http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm

```
window.open('URL','WINDOW NAME','width=width,height=height')
```